# Disable showing drives that are mulitpathed

Tags: redhat, rhel6

We have servers(RHEL 6.7) that have multipath SAN attached disks assigned to them. The multipathing is setup and all works great in that aspect. The issue comes in when you view the Computer within gnome, it shows all the drives. How do we get those drives not to show up? See attached image.

[image]

Comment: Remove gnome? ;)

Comment: Not really an option when the client wants it.

Comment: That was a joke, John. Hence the wink. As much as I'm opposed to having GUIs on *nix servers, Gnome clearly isn't the problem here.